# Sampling from two vectors with randsample

Tags: matlab, random

I have 2 vectors (**n** and **t**) eg:

```
n  t
1  5
5  3
5  2
2  6
2  9
```

Once I sample from vector **n** through `randsample(n,1)`, I want to sample from the vector **t** but only from the values corresponding to that same one in vector **n**.

eg.  If I drew a value of 2 from **n**, I then want to draw the value 6 or 9 from **t**. But how do I tell matlab to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple one-liner, assuming you have them stored in a `Nx2` matrix

```
nt = [
1  5;
5  3;
5  2;
2  6;
2  9];
```

meaning:

```
n = nt(:,1);
t = nt(:,2);
```

you can sample `nSamples` with replacement by randmonly indexing the matrix row-wise, i.e.:

```
nSamples = 5;
keepSamples = nt(randi(length(nt),nSamples,1),:);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could potentially do this:

```
out = t(n == randsample(n, 1))
```

This will create a filter based on whether n = its own random sample, ie if

```
randsample(n, 1) = 2
(n == randsample(n, 1)) = [0
                           0
                           0
                           1
                           1]
```

and applying this to t ie:

```
 t(n == randsample(n, 1)) = [6
                             9]
```

which are the two corresponding values to 2 in **n**, but in **t**.

Hope this helps.

PS if you need just one value from t then you can randsample the output that this function gives you.